# How can I get out of the loop once and for all?

Tags: powershell

I have this file:

```
function t {
    "abcd" -split "" |%{ if ($_ -eq "b") { return; } write-host $_; }
}
$o = @{}
$o |add-member -name t -membertype scriptmethod -value {
    "abcd" -split "" |%{ if ($_ -eq "b") { return; } write-host $_; }
}

write-host '-function-'
t;
write-host '-method-'
$o.t();
```

and if I run it I'll get:

```
-function-
a
c
d
-method-
a
c
d
```

as expected.  but if what I wanted was 'a', I could replace the `return` with `break`.  if I do so in the function what I get is:

```
-function-
a
```

so the method never even gets called.  if I replace it in the method, it won't compile (and complains about calling it).  what is going on here?

and what's the proper way to exit the foreach-object loop once and for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to rewrite it as a foreach statement, instead of using the ForEach-Object command, which is particularly hard to stop:

```
$o | add-member -name t -membertype scriptmethod -value {
    foreach($e in "abcd" -split "") {
        if ($_ -eq "b") { break }
        write-host $_; 
    }
}
```

As a side note, the `foreach(){}` keyword/construct runs a lot faster than piping through `ForEach-Object`.

For the sake of completeness ...

#### To stop a pipeline, throw PipelineStoppedException

```
"abcd" -split "" | % {
    if($_ -eq "b") {
      throw [System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException]::new() 
    }
    $_ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `break` to stop the ForEach, you use `return` since it's executed as a lambda on each member of the object anyway.